# Rails form_for NoMethodError - can't find where broken path is

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to make my CRM application works and can't figure out where broken part is.
When trying to create new contact, on link '/companies/1/contacts/new' 
got 'NoMethodError in Contacts#new'.

Screenshot is attached, see code below. Please help to find mistake..

[image]

route.rb is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :companies do
    resources :contacts do
      member do
        post :new
      end
    end
  end

  root 'companies#index'
end
```

Contacts Controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_company

  def index
    @contacts = Contact.where(company_id: params[:company_id])
  end

  def new; @contact = @company.contacts.new; end

  def create
    @contact = @company.contacts.create(contact_params)
    @contact.save ? redirect_to @company : render :new
  end

  private

  def set_company; @company = Company.find(params[:company_id]); end

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :position, :phone, :email)
  end
end
```

View:
new.html.erb:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', company_contacts_path %>
```

Form helper:

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the company as the first argument to `form_for`:

```
form_for(@company, @contact)
```

Then `form_for` will be able to infer the correct path.